# What am I missing: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
import hashlib
import csv
import glob

def hash(text):
    return hashlib.sha256(text.encode('UTF-8')).hexdigest()


def hash_file(input_file_name,output_file_name): 

    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as f_input, open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as f_output: 
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output) 
        csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))    # Copy the header row to the output
        count = 0
        print(count)

        for customer_email in csv_input:
            csv_output.writerow([hash(customer_email[0])])
            count = count + 1
            print(str(count) + " - " + customer_email[0])
        f_input.close()
        f_output.close

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]

for file in mylist:
    i_file_name = file
    o_file_name = "hashed-" + file 
    hash_file(i_file_name,o_file_name)
```

I'm trying the above code and I keep getting a list index out of range. I have about 15 csv files that I would like to hash the email address on. It gets the first csv file and keeps iterating through it until I get the error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the input files. See [how to create an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There was a blank line in my input that was causing the error

Comment: Please elaborate on where it was and how it caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

list index out of range mean that you try to acces a value of list by it's index, which is the length - 1 of the list value is not reach that index.

for example :

```
my_list = ['a', 'b']
lenght of my_list is 2. lenth - 1 = 1
```

mean that you only can acces the value of list until 1. like these:

```
my_list[0]
my_list[1]
```

if you try to access my_list[2], it will raise error list index out of range as your case.

to avoid the error you can:

```
index_to_access = 2
len(my_list) - index_to_access >=  and my_list[index_to_access]
```

in your case maybe at here:

```
csv_output.writerow([hash(customer_email[0])])
count = count + 1
print(str(count) + " - " + customer_email[0])
```

change to :

```
customer_email = len(customer_email) - 1 >= 0 and customer_email[0] or ''
csv_output.writerow([hash(customer_email)])
count = count + 1
print(str(count) + " - " + customer_email)
```

actually there are many ways to handle that error.